# A minimal normal subgroup of a solvable group is abelian

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

> A minimal normal subgroup of a solvable group is abelian.

I need to prove that this stands. However, I don't seem to understand the necessity of the group being solvable. Could you point out my mistake?

My proof goes as follows:

Let $H\triangleleft G$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose by contradiction $H$ isn't abelian. Then there exist $h_{1},h_{2}\in H$ s.t. $[H,H]\ni\left[h_{1},h_{2}\right]\neq e$. Since the commutator subgroup is always normal in the group, we get that $\{e\}\neq [H,H]\triangleleft H$ in contradiction to $H$ being a minimal subgroup.

Note - our exercises tend to be imprecise, so the question itself might be faulty.

Comment: You use solvability to conclude that $[H,H]\neq H$, which you need but never say explicitly. Minimality of $H$ tells you that $[H,H]=\{e\}$ (so $H$ is abelian) or $[H,H]=H$ (which would give you that $H$ is not solvable).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh right! That's what I was missing. If you'd like to, you can post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @DerekHolt I edited it away. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any group $G$, if $H$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ then your argument yields that $[H,H]=\{e\}$ or $[H,H]=H$.

If $[H,H]=\{e\}$ then $H$ is abelian; if $[H,H]=H$ then $H$ is perfect, so it is not solvable.

Since a subgroup of a solvable group is solvable, the latter possibility is excluded, so we conclude that $H$ is abelian.